# How to uninstall Corel Painter Internal Audio Driver in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extensions

I had installed Corel Painter 2016 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with its .pkg installer. I removed installed files from `/Applications/` by dragging them to the Trash.

Today I noticed that there is an additional item in the Output/Input Devices list at the menubar named `Internal Audio Driver (Corel Painter)`.
How can i uninstall it?

[image: List of audio devices]
[image: Audio MIDI Setup]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7420619?start=0&tstart=0) about uninstallation of this audio driver. There is a kernel extension named `PainterAudioDriver.kext` in `/System/Library/Extensions/` that adds the audio driver to the kernel space. To ensure that the kernel extension is loaded I used `kextstat`:

```
kextstat | grep corel
```

The result was:

```
  131    0 0xffffff7f80fde000 0x4000     0x4000     com.corel.painter.PainterAudioDriver (1) <96 5 4 3>
```

Then to unload the kernel extension I used `kextunload` that is explained [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/24/load-unload-kernel-extensions-mac-os-x/):

```
sudo kextunload -b com.corel.painter.PainterAudioDriver
```

After that the `Internal Audio Driver (Corel Painter)` is removed from both Sound menu bar and Audio MIDI Setup. To prevent the driver from loading again while rebooting the system, the kernel extension file must be removed from `/System/Library/Extensions/` with this command:

```
sudo rm -r /System/Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext
```

The Corel Painter Internal Audio Driver is uninstalled now.

Comment: In more recent versions of OSX (I believe starting with Sierra, and still true in Catalina), you'll find the .kext file to remove in `/Library/Extensions` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in one of the subfolders of /Library/Audio/ but then I do not have any custom audio drivers installed... so I can not confirm that!

If you still have the Corel Painter .pkg file you can open it as if you were going to reinstall it and look for a menu option "Show Files" that will shows you a complete list of every single file it would install. You can then scan through and look for /Library references to get an exact answer.

Comment: There are 6 folders in `/Library/Audio/` named: MIDI Configurations, MIDI Devices, MIDI Drivers, MIDI Patch Names, Plug-Ins, Sounds. But none of them (and subitems) are related to Corel Painter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Corel has for some reason set itself up as either an Aggregate or Multi-output  device in AudioMIDI

Applications > Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>  to show Audio devices if it doesn't show automatically.

If my suspicion is correct, you will see one of the 2 circled icons, named after Corel.

Select, then click the - sign underneath to remove.

[image]

This won't 'break' anything. These device types are user-created & deleted. It will not allow you to delete any real device.

Boom2 may also have set itself up in a similar way, so make sure to get the correct one, if you wish Boom2 to continue working correctly.

BTW, it is highly unlikely to have an actual associated driver installed, it is merely a way of 'patching' outputs for convenience, all done using Apple's own routing capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with details; but unfortunately the minus sign is remained disable and gray when I select `Internal Audio Driver (Corel Painter)` item.

Comment: can you add a picture of your audio MIDI setup to your question?

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223799/383276 the link here is the same answer given by Hamid...Its perfectly working so just use the commands given in the answer.