# How to remove when sudo rm says operation not permitted?

Tags: macos, permission, kernel-extensions

I'm trying to get rid of a stray kernel extension from Corel Painter. There is a question and answer about it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223551/how-to-uninstall-corel-painter-internal-audio-driver-in-os-x-yosemite). The `kextunload` command from that answer worked, but I can't remove the files.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext
rm: /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources:      Operation not permitted
rm: /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature: Operation not permitted
rm: /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS/PainterAudioDriver: Operation not permitted
...
rm: /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext: Operation not permitted
```

How can it not be permitted when I'm using sudo? How do I remove them?

I guess this has something to do with it...

```
% ls -ld@ /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  96 Jan  7  2016    /Library/Extensions/PainterAudioDriver.kext
       com.apple.rootless    0
```

Comment: This is because of [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) which is enforced because of the `com.apple.rootless` xattr, you will need to [disable it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/) to modify those files. (but this seems like an odd case because SIP shouldn't be protecting those files)

Comment: What version of macOS is running on this Mac?

Comment: The lastest: Catalina 10.15.4.

Comment: I disabled SIP, and still face this error